# PNG IDAT chunk data calculation

Tags: c, compression, png, zlib, deflate

I'm trying for learning propose to write my own png file in c language.
I have already read the PNG file format specification and i am now able to write a basic PNG(signature, IHDR CHUNK, 1px-IDAT CHUNK AND IEND CHUNK).
But now i want to write a array of pixels into the PNG, all chunks are going okk but I don't understand how to generate the IDAT data CHUNK.
In libPNG documentation they explain to deflate() the scanline, preced by the filer byte method.

My understanding of this problem:

A scanline is an array of horizontal pixels preceded by the filter method(0) then of size: (3*screenWidth + 1)
for each line (screenHeight value), I compress() the scanline with zlib and store it in a file.

But After generating the png, it is always black and the value is always 0 in hex editor.

what am i doing wrong? or is the the good way to generate IDAT data values?

Answer (score 0):

You did not put any code in your question, so we have no way of knowing what you're actually doing. "I compress() the scanline with zlib and store it in a file." sounds wrong. You need to assemble all of the scan lines as described, and then compress the entire thing with zlib, once.